# Bring button in front of an frame layout

Tags: android

I want to bring a button if front of an frame layout.
frame layout is View.GONE and when button is clicked it is set View.VISIBLE and it overflows Button.
I tried to set BringToFront but it didn't work need your help.

```
 slide_up3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.slide_up3);
            slide_up3.setAnimationListener(this);

            set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.animator.obj3);
            set.setTarget(flBlur);
            flBlur.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            set.start();
```

flBlur is background change and it covers the button that goes up

obj3 XML File

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<objectAnimator
    android:propertyName="backgroundColor"
    android:duration="500"
    android:valueFrom="@color/colorWednesdayBlur"
    android:valueTo="@color/colorWednesday"/>
```

slideup XML file

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="-200%"
```

frame layout XML file

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="@color/colorBcgLan"
    android:id="@+id/flBlur"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and the button is in the same frame layout and also in the relative layout

Comment: share the xml code?

Comment: shared XML code